# I don't get dialing screen in android

Tags: android

```
btnCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intentCall=new Intent();
                intentCall.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intentCall.setData(Uri.parse("Calling no.."+edtText.getText()));
                startActivity(intentCall);
            }
        });
```

Comment: add this, edtText.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
 Intent dial = new Intent();
    dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
    dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+edtText.getText().toString()));
    startActivity(dial);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+edtText.getText().toString()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Give your application permission to call in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```